# How to fetch only one project details in Power BI JIRA service

Tags: jira, powerbi, powerbi-datasource

I want to use Power BI JIRA service to analyze a particular project.
When I configure the URL and authentication in the service it fetches data set of all the projects in our organisation.
Currently I am using url in this format 
    https://organisationname.jira.com
Is there any way I can configure URL such that I fetch details of only one project?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question and had to add a few steps to @Nick Chopper's answer to get it working, But I'm using the template for on prim JIRA instances. Steps:-

Step 1: Add 'projectKey' parameter with type as text and enter the your project key in the current value field.

Step 2: Add the projectKey parameter to the FetchPages function and pass this parameter to the FetchPage function.

```
let
    FetchPages = (url as text, pageSize as number, projectKey as text) => 
let 
Source = GenerateByPage(
(previous) =>
let
    skipRows = if previous = null then 0 else Value.Metadata(previous)[skipRows],
    totalItems = if previous = null then 0 else Value.Metadata(previous)[total],
    table = if previous = null or Table.RowCount(previous) = pageSize then 
                FetchPage(url, pageSize, skipRows, projectKey) 
    else null
in table,

type table [Column1])
in
    Source
in
    FetchPages
```

Step 3: Add the projectKey parameter in FetchPage function and pass the projectKey to the JIRA web service as jql query.

```
let
    FetchPage = (url as text, pageSize as number, skipRows as number, projectKey as text) as table =>
    let
        //Here is where you run the code that will return a single page
        contents = Web.Contents(URL&"/rest/api/2/search",[Query = [maxResults= Text.From(pageSize), startAt = Text.From(skipRows), jql = "project="&projectKey]]),
        json = Json.Document(contents),
        Value = json[issues],
        table = Table.FromList(Value, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error)
    in
        table meta [skipRows = skipRows + pageSize, total = 500]
in
    FetchPage
```

Step 4: Refresh you data

Comment: when I do this solution, I'm getting the proper project, however, I'm only getting issues that are in open releases - I'd prefer to have all issues within a project and I can filter/group etc. by status.  Is there anyway to get everything, not just on open releases (it will grab done issues in open releases)

Comment: @Rob not sure why that might be happening, but I would verify if you are getting the same result from the JIRA UI using the advanced search/JQL https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirasoftwarecloud/advanced-searching-764478330.html

Comment: Figured it out - the issue was around the 500 record page size issue, the cloud version only lets me get 50 at a time.  So it didn't error, just didn't get me a full dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Using the power bi content pack create a project key parameter and enter the project key in the current value. The project key is the text strip that prefices your issue type number. example ZZZ-1096. Then add it to the fetchpages function
like this `= (url as text, pageSize as number, optional projectKey as text) => 
let 
    Source = GenerateByPage(
    (previous) =>
    let
        skipRows = if previous = null then 0 else Value.Metadata(previous)[skipRows],`

That is right out of the power bi connector from [here](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/explore-your-jira-data-with-power-bi/).